# Mule cluster configuration issue

Tags: mule

I have a mule cluster with 2 nodes running in different machines, cluster configured through mmc with tomcat. when I deploy application in mmc cluster, applications are deploying 2 nodes. I have quartz scheduler, which runs nightly build.

```
<quartz:connector name="Quartz" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="my-app1"/>
</quartz:connector>

<quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="Fetch" repeatInterval="0" repeatCount="0" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" startDelay="0" cronExpression="${cronExpression}" connector-ref="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
</quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

Now, when application starts at 11pm, application is running in both the nodes. This causes duplicate of processing records i.e processing same application in 2 machines. Mule cluster is HA-Active-Active mode, what I need is at any given time only one node should process and if there is a huge load then other server should process it, even failure of one server should pickup the other server up and running. Instead of doing this, scheduler runs in both application in parallel. How to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a cluster only one Quartz inbound endpoint should be triggered. If this is not happening please open a support case with our support team. About distributing messages under hight load, you should put a vm outbound endpoint after the quartz inbound endpoint and the rest of your flow logic in a different flow that listen to those messages in a vm inbound endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

If things does not work out, you can have a temporary workaround where , flow which has only the quarts endpoint and then a JSM queue which will send a nearly balanced messages to two nodes .

Here the quarts and the JMS combination should be deployed only in one server.